# Doctrine Mongodb Id is blank

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following code in `PostController` of my `Symfony2` application

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();

$fields = array('id','title', 'content');
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:BlogPost')
    ->select($fields);

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$blogPosts = $query->execute();

return $this->render('post/list.html.twig',array('posts' => $blogPosts));
```

And the following in it's view

```
<ol id="navigation">
    {% for post in posts %}
        <li> {{ post.id }} - {{ post.content }} <a href="{{path('delete')}}?id={{ post.id }}">delete</a> </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

However, the `id` field returned to the view is always blank. I tried clearing the cache many times but still the `id` is blank. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: isnt the field called `_id` ?

Comment: `id` can also be used. The problem was that the `id` field did not have a getter/setter in my `BlogPost` entity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It was pretty simple. I didn't have setter/getter for `id` field in `AppBundle:BlogPost` entity. Apparently,  `Doctrine Mongodb` uses the getter/setter to populate values from the the db.

UPDATE: It's not `Doctrine` but `Twig` template engine which requires the getter/setter.

```
/** @ODM\Id */
protected $id;

public function setId($valId){
    $this->id=$valId;
}

public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}
```

Comment: Actually, Doctrine will hydrate the properties directly, but it is Twig who will try to call the getter when you do `post.id`. I also suggest you follow the common practice of camel-casing your methods. eg. `getId()`.

Comment: Thanks. I already use camelcasing but did want to avoid it in this case thinking that the getter/setter won't be invoked if it didn't match the property name which is `id`

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I suggest you read up here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables. Under *Implementation* you can find how exactly the dot accessor works.